# Where is my Flashback Metacity Session?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, metacity

Recently I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04. On log-in screen I always had Flashback Metacity and Compiz Sessions (beside Unity) and I used Metacity (heavily customized). Because I had problems with Nautilus (did not open as root) I reinstalled it. After that I lost Metacity and Compiz options and was stuck with only Unity. How can I get them back (with my customization)? I have tried restoring backed up files from a week ago, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing GNOME Flashback (from terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-flashback
```

That will give you back GNOME Flashback (Compiz) and GNOME Flashback (Metacity) sessions in your login screen.